# How to prevent WP adding extra line after inserting/replacing text from TinyMCE popup?

Tags: tinymce, wordpress

I'm building a WP plugin that has a shortcode admin in a TinyMCE popoup. Whenever I'm done it inserts everything properly but it also adds a new line every time.

My script is very similar to this: http://pastebin.com/RVXfrQL9

`tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', false, output);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the quoted line to:

```
myeditorName.selection.setContent(output);
```

And it works!

Answer (score 2):

do you mean the [autop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)??

try -

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

Comment: Good one but no that another thing :)